# Remove jQuery function on screen resize

Tags: jquery, css, resize, screen-size

I've created a jQuery function to show a div that should work just when the screen size is more than 1000px.

The function works properly but it doesn't work when I resize the screen because the jQuery function has already been loaded. So when I resize the screen, the function keeps staying there.

Is there a way to remove this script once I resized the screen and it is smaller than 1000px?

At the moment the script works just when I open the webpage and the screen is already smaller than 1000px but not when I resize the screen

This is what I have now.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(window).resize(function() {
        if(jQuery(window).width() >= 1000) {

          jQuery("#mega-menu-projects").mouseover(
              function(){
                  jQuery("#mega-menu-projects").show();
              }
          );

          jQuery("#mega-menu-projects").mouseout(
              function(){
                  jQuery("#mega-menu-projects").hide();
              }
          );

        }
    }).resize();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using CSS [`@media`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media)

```
#mega-menu-projects{
  display:none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  #mega-menu-projects{
    display:block;
  }
}
```

Comment: If there really is something you wish about mouse events... Please explain. ;)

Comment: I didn't think about using CSS, simple and rapid. Thanks! Just added this to my CSS file: @media screen and (max-width: 999px) { #mega-menu-projects { display: none !important; }

Answer (score 0):

You should just change your logic. You can leave the event listener there but cancel it after checking if the screen size isn't the one you want:

```
jQuery("#mega-menu-projects").mouseover(function(){
    if (jQuery(window).width() < 1000) return;
    jQuery("#mega-menu-projects").show();
});

jQuery("#mega-menu-projects").mouseout(function () {
    if (jQuery(window).width() < 1000) return;
    jQuery("#mega-menu-projects").hide();
});
```

Comment: But there is something weird there that I don't understand. You'll show the element only if you hover over it, is that it? Because if so, it'll not work. You cannot trigger a hover event on a hidden element.

Answer (score 0):

with jQuery, you can remove event listeners using [.off](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

It would be simple enough to add an else clause that removes the mouseover and mouseout events if the screen smaller than you need it to be.

Something like (untested)

```
else {
    jQuery("#mega-menu-projects").off()
}
```

That said, if all you're trying to do is add/remove visual open/close functionality on hover based on screen size. You'll have a better time doing it in CSS using [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

with which you can add/remove hover states based on the screen size

```
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
    #mega-menu-projects:hover{
        ...
    }
}
```